# A question about vector valued $L^2$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$ finite measure space.
Suppose that $U$ is a bounded linear operator on $L^2(\Omega , H)$ which commutes with the multiplication operator by a  $g \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I want to define a bounded linear operator $R(\omega)$ on $H$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
R(\omega)(g(\omega)\varphi(\omega)) = g(\omega) U(\varphi)(\omega)
\end{equation*}
 I define $R(\omega)$ as above exactly, linearity is clear , but i cant show that $R(\omega)$ is bounded unfortunately. Can you help me? Thanks.